# Random selection of images at wp7

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-7

I have two pages at my project and when i navigate from page1 to page2 i load a picture at a stackpanel using the code below

```
var imageResource = Application.GetResourceStream(
          new Uri("WindowsPhonePuzzle;component/numbers/numbergame.png",
          UriKind.Relative));   
 this.ImageStream = imageResource.Stream;
```

if I want to have two or more pictures and load each time a random of them or at a row 
what I have to change ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to store the Uris of the images you want to use in some kind of Collection. Then use Random to select one.

```
Random r = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
int index = r.Next(0, myCollection.Count);
var imageResource = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(myCollection[i], UriKind.Relative)); 
this.ImageStream = imageResource.Stream;
```

You could also directly access the resources but you'll need to make sure you're dealing with a Uri to an image.

Comment: how can i create i collection is there any example?  sorry but i am an amateur.  When you say directly access what do u mean ?

Comment: How/Where do you specify what images are available for display? Do you drag them into a folder in your project-tree? This is hard for me to tell without more knowlegde about your project. Also, I dont have access to WP7 dev-tools atm.